# Is it possible to let 'make' utilize all the isolated cpus for its parallel build jobs?

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-make, cpu-usage

My x64 machine is running CentOS 8 and has 20 cpus.

Out of 20 cpus, only 2 cpus (0 and 1) are available for normal use and the rest 18 cpus (2-19) are isolated.

When I try `taskset -c 2-19 make -j 15` for example, only 1 cpu out of the 18 seems to be used.

It looks like the cpuset specified by taskset is not applied to child processes.

Is it possible to let make and all the child processes fully utilize the isolated cpus?

Comment: I too am looking for a way to do this.